# Own JQuery's .text() with NodeJS/Cheerio

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to code jQuery.fn.text with NodeJS/Cheerio.

I did that :

```
function getText(elems) {
      var ret = '', elem;

      for (var i = 0; elems[i]; i++) {
        elem = elems[i];

        // Get the text from text nodes
        if (elem.nodeType === 3) {  
          ret += elem.nodeValue;
        } else if (elem.nodeType !== 8) { 
          // Traverse everything else, except comment nodes
          ret += getText(elem.childNodes);
        }
      }

      return ret;
}

request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.lemonde.fr/',
}, (error, response, html) => {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  console.log(getText($('body')));    
});
```

but I don't get the same result between `console.log(getText($('body')))` & `console.log($('body').text())`.
With `getText` some text is missing. The result is not complete.

**Clarification:**
I know how to use jQuery.fn.text. I just want to know how to get the text of an element à la jQuery with NodeJS/Cheerio.

Comment: All you need is the native `textContent` property of the parent element, potentially with some amendments to handle any whitespace/line breaks. If this doesn't work for you could you please add the HTML to the question along with the output you expect

Comment: jQuery runs on the client side while Node.js/Cheerio runs on the server side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The html code is the one of the www.lemonde.fr website.Expected output is result of `console.log($('body').text())`
I can't reach him because he's too important. The same is true for the output.

Answer (score 0):

The node.js/cheerio code should go in a separate file which runs on the server-side.

```
//cheerio-test.js

const request = require('request');
const $ = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.lemonde.fr/', (error, response, html) => {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  console.log( $('body').html() ); //or console.log( $('body').text() );   
});
```

You would need the right environment on your server including `npm`, `nodejs`, `package.json` and `request` & `cheerio` installed using npm. Then, on the command line, just run:

```
node cheerio-test
```

**Reference**

[node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

[cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/)

Comment: I Know NodeJS/Cheerio environnement. My question is that I don't get the same result between `console.log($('body').text())` & `console.log(getText($('body')))`